# How to modify Django's DateTimeInput widget to select times at 15-minute increments instead of 30?

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a default `DateTimeField` which includes a drop-down menu for the time of day in 30-minute increments:

[image]

I'd like to change this so that times are selectable at 15-minute increments instead of 30-minute ones.

Looking into Django's source code (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py) for the `DateTimeInput` widget (which is the default `widget` for `DateTimeField`), it is not immediately clear to me how I would customize it to adjust the interval spacing:

```
class DateTimeInput(DateTimeBaseInput):
    format_key = 'DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS'
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/datetime.html'
```

Any ideas how I might go about this customization? Or should I choose a different, readily available widget?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer has not so much to do with Django as with the time picker that was being used: [pickatime.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#picker). Simply passing in the option `interval: 15` (overriding the default `interval: 30`) solved the problem.